# How to join Lists together based on a value in C#

Tags: c#, list

I currently have multiple train stations that hold trains arriving at different times. Each train has a unique identifier so other stations know where that train is coming from / going to.

Here is an example of how a train is constructed:

```
class App
{
    public static List<Station> Stations = new List<Station>()
    {
        new Station()
        {
            Name = "Birmingham New Street",

            TrainsArriving = new List<Train.Train> ()
            {
                new Train.Train()
                {
                    ID = "X1001",
                    Arrival = DateTime.Now,
                    Carriges = new List<Carrige>()
                    {
                        new Carrige()
                    }
                },

                new Train.Train()
                {
                    ID = "Y1001",
                    Arrival = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),
                    Carriges = new List<Carrige>()
                    {
                        new Carrige()
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        new Station()
        {
            Name = "Marston Green",

            TrainsArriving = new List<Train.Train> ()
            {
                new Train.Train()
                {
                    ID = "X1001",
                    Arrival = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                    Carriges = new List<Carrige>()
                    {
                        new Carrige()
                    }
                },

                new Train.Train()
                {
                    ID = "Y1001",
                    Arrival = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(50),
                    Carriges = new List<Carrige>()
                    {
                        new Carrige()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I want to now search the trains that depart from Birmingham New Street and Arrive At Marston Green. This should give me two different trains, X1001 and T1001 as a `List<Train>`.

I have tried to use `Intersect` but cannot figure out how to join the Lists based on the ID property.

So far, this is my attempt:

```
Train.Station departingStation = App.Stations.Find(x => x.Name.Equals("Birmingham New Street"));
Train.Station arrivingStation = App.Stations.Find(x => x.Name.Equals("Marston Green"));

List<Train> trains = departingStation.TrainsArriving.Intersect(arrivingStation.TrainsArriving).ToList();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: The trains should query based on time ascending. Only bring out trains that are moving in the future, not past (that way we can find the trains departing and arriving and not heading backwards).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not call it join, but to get *trains that depart from Birmingham New Street and Arrive At Marston Green* you can use `Where` clause to filter the trains from `departingStation`:

```
var trains = departingStation.TrainsArriving
    .Where(dt => arrivingStation.TrainsArriving.Any(at => at.ID == dt.ID && at.Arrival > dt.Arrival))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This makes sense now! Thank you so much! I'll mark this when I can

Comment: @Jaquarh was glad to help!

Comment: My mind is extra blown, if I add a second train station, ie "Birmingham Moor Street" but the Departing station has no direct trains to the arriving station, how could I find a List of Stations that reach the Arriving Station in time order? (is your mind as blown?) lol ie: Marston > Moor Street has to go: Marston > New Street > Moor Street and change at New Street. [Here is an updated dataset](https://pastebin.com/U230NCny)

Comment: @Jaquarh I would suggest you to look into `SelectMany` selecting some new descriptor like `(TrainId, StationName, Train)` then grouping by `TrainId` and ordering by time.

Comment: I looked into this but can't find a way to find the Stations in between using the train ID. I can figure out the logic I need, only, I am not a C# developer so the syntax for LINQ I am not used to. I just need to filter all of the stations that are between 2 stations based on trains that arrive at them in time order.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use Linq.
If you only need trains Departing from Birmingham New Street and arriving at Marston Green you will need to sort on the Arrival-time as well

```
List<Train> trains =  departingStation.TrainsArriving.
   Where(t => arrivingStation.TrainsArriving.
   Any(a=>t.ID==a.ID && t.Arrival < a.Arrival )).ToList();
```

Comment: for eligible trains, arrival time must be greater than departure time (i.e your arrival comparison must be reversed, like a.Arrival > t.Arrival)